# DDD - Consistency of Entity Across Bounded Context & Different Schemas in Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, domain-driven-design

I am implementing DDD with Entity Framework Code First. My Domain Model is persisted as it is without any mapping layer.

I am following approach suggested during [Tech-Ed](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2014/DEV-B411) by Julie Lerman. Each bounded context maps to different schema within same database.

> If same entity say, Customer appears across different bounded contexts
>   how do we maintain consistency of data for Customer entity?

Answer (score 10):

Only a single bounded context will be the [system of record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_record) for your entity.  If you cannot get away with simply an Id in the other BCs then you can include a subset of the entity (usually not all the properties) as a value object.

Any changes to the entity in the SOR should be published as one or more events in a messaging system that the downstream BCs subscribe to in order to keep their data *eventually consistent*.

Comment: Thanks, Entity framework expects navigation property to be present in either side of the association, otherwise I could have well managed with foreign keys rather than breaking my EF context into multiples. Any thoughts on workaround of this?

Comment: Unfortunately I am no fan of any ORM tool.  However, it should not be an issue either way since you should have a very hard boundary around your aggregate.  So you will be loading either only the Id for the foreign/upstream AR or a value object.  I do not know how EF would re-constitute a VO.  I think NHibernate has a *component* or something to that effect.  EF should have something similar.

Answer (score 3):

In Julie Lerman's example with Entity Framework (EF) she models a `Contact` under two different bounded contexts - `Sales Order` (being read only) and `Contact Management` (being persistable)).  As Eben suggests keeping these entities eventually consistent can be achieved using a messaging system - in Julie's example she uses the `ContactUpdatedEvent` domain event which can be subscribed to by a service to enforce a model within a different bounded context to be reread from a data source (whether this is a database or the event itself contains the data in a DTO for example) when this event is published - this will help ensure *eventual* consistency of data.

Because your controller/view model/presenter/services should be interacting directly with an abstracted interface for persisting changes, i.e. the repository pattern rather than the EF db context directly, then in the example above one `Contact` will come from one repository under one root aggregate and the other `Contact` will come under another root aggregate - therefore the two `Contact` entity implementations will support persistence of the root aggregates in different ways, in which the `Sales Order` context will prevent the persistency of the `Contact` entity.

As you will represent the `Contact` under two different bounded contexts they shouldn't share the same behaviour so you shouldn't really worry about any code duplication apart from the naming of properties for getting/setting data, but I'm sure this is something you can live with.  For example, an action of "Asking a contact to review their order" COULD be represented with behaviour on the `Contact` class under the `Contact Management` context, but MAY have no relevance in the `Contact` class on the `Sales Order` context.

The EF doesn't force you to have associations between entities in both directions.  The Fluent API mapping provides a lot of flexibility and can allow you to have these associations one way.

If the idea of your project is to follow DDD then I'd suggest you forget about the database and EF completely to start with and use in-memory repositories for reading and persisting your root aggregates.  You can then focus on mapping your domain entities to your database using the EF Fluent API at a later date and this way you won't be forced to change your domain model to "fit" your database.