# Mapping DDD domain models to EF POCO

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design

If there are two Customer domain models representing different bounded contexts (with different/overlapping fields), how are you supposed to Update this certain X bounded context Customer in the database that might be holding both those Customer domains in one POCO (or maybe Y bounded context Customer additionally uses a list of Orders of this same context)?

Also I could put it this way. How do you solve cases when domain models maps many to one with the database POCO?

Does it mean that repository would have to query db once more, but this time whole POCO object from DB, update its values accordingly and finally make the update?

Comment: Different contexts have their own DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DDD - Consistency of Entity Across Bounded Context & Different Schemas in Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389100/ddd-consistency-of-entity-across-bounded-context-different-schemas-in-databa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you provided the 2 contexts and overlapping attributes of Customer. For the purpose of this answer Ill use the contexts: 'Sales' and 'Marketing' and the shared attribute is 'Preferred Name'

My initial thought based on the phrase 'overlapping fields' is that you need to revisit your model as you should not have 2 models responsible for a specific value otherwise you have concurrency/race conditions.

Try and think how your clients would resolve the situation in the old days of pen & paper. Who would own the 'customer' file? Would sales and marketing each have their own version, or would marketing rely on sales copy (or visa versa)?

Also, one of the most powerful aspects of DDD is it forces your persistence concerns way out into you infrastructure layers where they belong. You do not have to use EF for all your repository calls, if it easier to hand craft some sql for a specific persistence call then do it.

**--Scenario 1: Overlapping field is not overlapping--**

In this case, the domain experts came to realise that Sales.Customer.PreferredName and Marketing.Customer.PreferredName are independent attributes and can be different between contexts. Marketing often used the field for their cute *we are you best pals* campaign correspondence whilst Sales preferred to keep on file the most un-ambiguous

The CUSTOMER database table has 2 fields: PreferredNameSale and PreferredNameMarketing.

The 2 Concrete Repositories will end up looking something like:

```
class Sales.Repositories.ClientRepository : Domain.Sales.IClientRepository {
    Update(Domain.Sales.Client salesClient) {
        using (var db = new MyEfContext()) {
            var dbClient = db.Client.Fetch(salesClient.Id);
            dbClient.PreferredNameSales = salesClient.PreferredName;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

class Marketing.Repositories.ClientRepository : Domain.Marketing.IClientRepository {
    Update(Domain.Marketing.Client marketingClient) {
        using (var db = new MyEfContext()) {
            var dbClient = db.Client.Fetch(marketingClient.Id);
            dbClient.PreferredNameMarketing = marketingClient.PreferredName;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Entity Framework *should* notice that only 1 field was changed and send the appropriate `update client set field=newvalue where id=1` to the database.

There should be no concurrency issues when sales and marketing update their version of a single clients preferred name at the same time.

Also note that EF is providing a lot of overhead and very little value here. The same work could be completed with a simple parameterised  `SqlCommand.Execute()`

**--Scenario 2: Overlapping field is overlapping--**

Your model is broken but it is too late to fix it properly. You lie to yourself that the chances of sales and marketing trying to change the preferred name at the same time is tiny and even if it happens, it should be rare that hopefully the user will blame themselves for not using the system correctly.

In this case, there is only one database field: client.PreferredName and as with scenario 1, the functions work on the same table/field:

```
class Sales.Repositories.ClientRepository : Domain.Sales.IClientRepository {
    Update(Domain.Sales.Client salesClient) {
        using (var db = new MyEfContext()) {
            var dbClient = db.Client.Fetch(salesClient.Id);
            dbClient.PreferredName = salesClient.PreferredName;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

class Marketing.Repositories.ClientRepository : Domain.Marketing.IClientRepository {
    Update(Domain.Marketing.Client marketingClient) {
        using (var db = new MyEfContext()) {
            var dbClient = db.Client.Fetch(marketingClient.Id);
            dbClient.PreferredName = marketingClient.PreferredName;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The Obviously problem is that a save at the same time by both sales and marketing will end up with last one wins in terms of persisted data. You can try and mitigate this with lastupdated timestamps and so on but it will just get more messy and broken. Review your model and remember: DB MODEL != DOMAIN MODEL != UI View Model

Comment: Very detailed answer. By saying overlapping I meant data that will be used across bounded contexts. According to DDD it is not bad to keep duplicates of fullname in these contexts. Because one of these contexts would be responsible for moderating fullname and every other context that has only read-only access would be eventually consistent (domain events).

Comment: One more question. If Marketing.Customer is the core one and is responsible to keep common properties consistent, does it really mean that if Marketing.Customer gets created, all other BCs should also create their customer with the information that was provided? (this would feel incorrect, because lack of data in Sales should not let to create Sales.Customer without sales specific properties). So, when and how Sales should get this common data.

Thanks for your insights

Comment: You will need to define 'Used', I get the feeling in this case it is something like 'I need the name and address over here and here' to which I would ask 'Do you really?' - Sales sounds like it could be done with just a customer ID. 

Don't confuse the needs of your UI with the needs of your domain Model, use (domain defined anemic) views as required. Also, if Marketing 'owns' customer data, then it doesn't restrict your UI or applications working across BC's and leveraging the Marketing.Customer * models and repo's.

Comment: You might be right. When I say 'used', I automatically include everything that this BC would need to live as a separate module. Even for UI, if there is a need to display some data related to Sales, you can not do that, because it does not have data that is only required for UI representation. So, you either somehow combine multiple BCs reads or create a totally separate model for UI representation. How do you solve it?

Comment: It sounds like  you are letting your UI dictate the terms of your Domain. Business needs should be the only|primary driver of your domain model. Use appropriately exposed database views were appropriate, if your sales page needs to *display* User, Product , Cart and Inventory entity data, create a view(s) in your DB that contains all this info and use that rather than going through the wasteful exercise of creating instances of your Domain Objects that you wont do any 'work' on.

Comment: This would work if your BCs schemas live in the same database. (which would be the way from my point of view). But what if your BCs have  separate databases?

Comment: (I think we are abusing the comments - ) If they are truly in separate bounded context then there are various mechanisms you can use (google Domain events) to communicate between them, but doing this the business is saying there is a marketing client entity and a sales client entity. You need to confirm: Are marketing and Sales separate contexts? Do they have their own Ubiquitous Language? Or are they just separate aggregate roots  inside your one 'MyShop' context (You don't need multiple bounded contexts for DDD) PS: Views can work across databases

Answer (score 0):

- Each bounded context is required to have its own database. That is it, there should be no discussion here. Violating this rule leads to severe consequences, which have been discussed many times.
- Overlapping fields smell, different bounded contexts have different concerns and therefore do not require to have much data to share. The best case is when the only thing you share is the aggregate identity. If in your world you have one *Customer* that have different concerns handled by two different bounded contexts, you can use one *CustomerId* value for both bounded contexts.
- If you really need to sync some data, you need to have it in both models, therefore in both persistent stores (I intentionally avoid the word *database* here) and you can sync the data using domain events. This is very common.

Comment: Well, I do understand your first point. Separate databases eliminate the temptation and technical posibility to couple BCs. But this is just up to developer to decide if he is taking shortcuts. There might be other more reasonable limitations to keep everything within same database but keep schemas separate and get rid of bad habits. For example, running separate databases in the cloud would be much more expensive approach compared to a single one. Of course "it depends", but this is just an example.

Am I missing here something?